# Why when you use ng-src in angular you have to use an expression?

Tags: angularjs

ng-src='{{item.img[0]}}'

when...

other directives just take a string like ng-show='item.val'

I am not sure why the expression is used in some cases and why the string is in others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just the way it is implemented.

The reason the chose to use an interpolated expression is that it allows you to do this:

```
ng-src="http://my.generic.url/some/resource/{{IDdefinedInScope}}"
```

---

If it didn't use interpolation, you would have to do either this:

```
ng-src="'http://my.generic.url/some/resource/' + IDdefinedInScope"
```

or that:

```
ng-src="someResourceUrl(IDdefinedInScope)"

$scope.someResourceUrl = function (id) {
    return 'http://my.generic.url/some/resource/' + id;
};
```

(...which are more verbose and clamsy and less declarative.)

---

<sub>Of cource, what makes this possible here is that the output needs to ve a string (and not an object).</sub>

Comment: A break of consistency for some convenience usually is more of an inconvenience for users.   If its not logical when use what case, users are forced to lookup the syntax.  Good Answer tho. ty

Comment: There is no consistency broken here. There are several attribute-directives that take an interpolated expression. You probably happened to mostly use ones that don't, but `ngSrc` is definitely **not** "one of a kind" :) Angular's directives are exactly the same as everyone else's custom directives and they can (and will) use either form...

Comment: Atleast its fits in with everything else in JS, there is more than one way to do everything!

Answer (score 2):

I've wondered this myself. Following the source brings us back to when angular was in it's infancy. This is about 100 commits before their first 0.9 version: [9627c4b50e](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/9627c4b50e1f8964fc59b0c2fd4914bd67514041), Issue [#11](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/11)

It turns out that there is no extended commit message, nor any issue message. The code resides at the bottom of [/src/markups.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/9627c4b50e1f8964fc59b0c2fd4914bd67514041/src/markups.js), with very little comments in the source and definitely not any sort of doc. So the following is just my *conjecture*, and might not be accurate.

It seems in the early beginnings of angular, they defined about 6 different tools: directives, filters, formatters, markups, validators, and widgets. Going forward a few commits, I found these definitions:

- Directives create custom attributes for DOM elements, but were not to add elements to the dom.
- Widgets can be either create a custom attribute that modifies an existing DOM element or an entirely new DOM element.
- Filters are used for formatting data displayed to the user.
- Formatters are used for translating data formats between those used for display and those used for storage.
- Validators are used to check user input against defined types or patterns.
- Markup transforms content of DOM elements or portions of this content into other text or DOM elements.

At that point Directives/Widgets used expressions, Markups used {{interpolation}}, Filters used a pipe | inside of interpolation, and Formatters/Validators used plain text. ng-href and ng-src fell under the markup category.

Comparing to now (1.3), Directives, Widgets, and Markups are now merged together into Directives. Filters and Formatters are now just Filters, and Validators are inside a form element's ngModelController.

Because of this migration, they had to decided what to do with the markups. They changed a lot of the boolean markups (ng-checked/multiple/readonly/selected/disabled) to expressions, but decided to keep ng-src and ng-href as interpolation.  You can find [a discussion on google groups where Misko Hevery explains the exception](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/TU5L8pI2a5E/W34Ekpd8444J).

So it was derived from early categorization, and persisted for simplicity's or backwards-compatibility's sake.